# JavaScript - innerHTML does not run independently in setInterval

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval, innerhtml

This is my first JS question. I have this function that is inside a setInterval. So this function gets repeated.

```
function chooseAnswer() {
correct.onclick = function() {
    if (range == 0) {
        score++;
        isGameOver = false;
    }
    else {
        isGameOver = true;
    }
}

incorrect.onclick = function() {
    if (range != 0) {
        score++;
        isGameOver = false;
    }
    else {
        isGameOver = true;
    }
}

// Display score
displayScore.innerHTML = score;
}
```

Everything works perfectly, except the score (innerHTML) does not update right away after the onlick is triggered. It waits until next round of time interval to update. However, if I move

```
displayScore.innerHTML = score;
```

and put it right after

```
score++;
```

in either of the if statement, the score will update right away after the onlick is triggered. Why does this happen? Doesn't this function works independently regardless of the setInterval? That is, it executes line by line, so the

```
displayScore.innerHTML = score;
```

will update right away, it does not have to wait till next round.

Comment: How have you got the setInterval() set up?

Comment: It is not clear why - in your first code block - you think `displayScore.innerHTML = score;` would update the `displayScore` immediately after a click.  If a click occurs, only the code in the callback is executed.  `correct.onclick = function() { .... }`, does not pause the execution, it sets the `onclick`  callback for the element.

Comment: It's just a simple setInterval, window.setInterval (chooseAnswer, 5000), that is right above my chooseAnswer () function.

Comment: @t.niese: Okay, so when either of the onlick is triggered, does everything after it gets ignored? Is it like "continue" inside a loop?

Answer (score 0):

This is more a comment but because it is to long I'll write it here:

This is not related to `continue` in a loop. When `chooseAnswer` is called, no matter if manually or by `setInterval`. Then three statements are executed:

1. the assignment of the callback to `correct.onclick`
2. the assignment of the callback to `incorrect.onclick`
3. `displayScore.innerHTML = score;`

The callbacks itself are just stored in `onclick` at that time, but they are not executed/evaluated at that moment. Only at the time when you click on `correct` or `incorrect`  then the browser will check if a callback is stored in `onclick`  and if there is one, then it will be executed. But this callback only contains this code:

```
function() {
  if (range == 0) {
    score++;
    isGameOver = false;
  } else {
    isGameOver = true;
  }
}
```

the following code is equivalent to yours, but with another structure and might be more understandable:

```
function correctCallback() {
  if (range == 0) {
    score++;
    isGameOver = false;
  } else {
    isGameOver = true;
  }
}

function incorrectCallback() {
  if (range != 0) {
    score++;
    isGameOver = false;
  } else {
    isGameOver = true;
  }
}

function chooseAnswer() {
  correct.onclick = correctCallback; //correctCallback is not call but just assigned to correct.onclick
  incorrect.onclick = incorrectCallback; //incorrectCallback is not call but just assigned to correct.onclick

  // Display score
  displayScore.innerHTML = score;
}
```

Further more it does not make sense to overwrite the `onclick` in the interval over and over again.

Comment: I guess my question is, what happens AFTER one of the button is clicked? When will the "executed line" be?

Comment: @PhuLe What do you mean with `executed line` and  with `When will the "executed line" be`? The  JavaScript engine is waiting for any input of the user  if a click happens on an element the JavaScript engine checks if there is an callback function registered for that event  and will execute those callback functions, and then it will wait again for input or to execute other code that was queued using `setTimeout` or `setInterval`. But the event handling happens after the `chooseAnswer` has been executed.